# How to improve performance of jQuery Tokeninput plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-tokeninput

I'm using the tokeninput plugin from http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/ to implement an autocomplete textbox with the selected items appear as Facebook-like tokenized tags.

```
$("#Friends").tokenInput("MyPath/GetTokens", {
        theme: "facebook"
}
```

However, it takes a long time to load the search results each time the user types in a search letter, probably because the call to GetTokens is made each time.  Is there a way I can improve the speed?  Could I store the GetTokens response into a javascript array and use that as my source instead of calling GetTokens each time?  If so could someone help me out with the syntax?  I'm not sure how I'd use a Javascript array for the Get call.